# Map checkbox inputs group to AngularJS array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I need to map a list of a selected checkbox to an javascript (AngularJS) array. When the user select one checkbox I need to update the related array. This array must have this structure:

```
$scope.items = ["value specific selected checkbox1", "value specific selected checkbox2"]
```

I use ng-true-value directive in my input tag to set a specific value of a selected checkbox to add to items array.

If the user unselect one checkbox I need to remove the specific value from items array. The array should not have duplicate values.

Comment: Hmmm... I am missing some code to see what have you done already and  where you got stuck...

Comment: I need to write the logic to map a group of checkboxes into my items array.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model

Otherwise, you can create your own directive which would use the ngModelController of your checkbox ($formatters and $parsers):

- Formatter: your model is an array, you return true or false depending if the value of your checkbox is inside this array.
- Parser: if it is checked, you add your checkbox value to the array, otherwise you remove it.